# how is the not operator in the module require working

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, commonjs

I was going through an open source editor project, when i encountered this strange require syntax

[var editorCss = require("./requirejs/text!./css/editor.css");](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js#L47)

can anybody tell me what this line is doing? what is the `!.` in the require path? is that acting as some parameter being passed into the file that is getting required from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclamation point makes RequireJS use a plugin to perform the load. What comes before the exclamation point is the plugin, and what comes after is what the plugin must load. The `require("./requirejs/text!./css/editor.css");` tells RequireJS "load the plugin `./requirejs/text` and, using this plugin, load `./css/editor.css`.

This syntax happens to be part of the AMD spec: RequireJS is compliant and so supports it. Other loaders that support AMD may also support it.

Comment: can this syntax be used in the node require?

Comment: No, Node's `require` is not AMD-compliant. It follows the CommonJS standard. You can use [this Node package](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader) to get Node to load AMD  modules directly but it does not support plugins *generally*. It *will* work with `text!something` but it does this by "cheating". It won't load the plugin and won't pass control to it. It just detects the use of `text!` and uses `fs.readFileSync` to return the contents of the module directly.

Comment: i am already using the amd loader, but i am getting `Running "browserify:main" (browserify) task
>> Error: Cannot find module './requirejs/text!./css/editor.css'
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
` 
while browserifying

Comment: Looks like Browserify does not understand that syntax natively. I'd suggest searching for [tag:browserify] questions on SO. If you don't find a question like your that already has an answer, you could write a question that illustrates the problem you ran into.